# ORACLE constraints based on 2+ tables

Tags: oracle

I have the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Flights (
  route_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  operated_by INT NOT NULL,
  airplane_model  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  source VARCHAR(20),
  destination VARCHAR(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (operated_by) REFERENCES Airline(airline_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (airplane_model) REFERENCES Airplanes(airplane_id)
  );
CREATE TABLE outgoing (
  route_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  poTime Date NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (route_number) REFERENCES Flights(route_number)
);

    CREATE TABLE incoming (
    route_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    paTime date NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (route_number) REFERENCES Flights(route_number)
  );
  CREATE TABLE departures(
    depid int not null PRIMARY KEY,
  route_number INT NOT NULL,
   gate VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    depT date NOT NULL,
    depD date NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (route_number) REFERENCES Flights(route_number)
);  

      CREATE TABLE ARRIVALS(
  route_number INT NOT NULL,
   gate VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    arrT date NOT NULL,
    arrD date NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(10),
    arrid int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (route_number) REFERENCES Flights(route_number)
);
```

I am trying to create a constraint that no two flights can have the same gate during a planned time (paTime and poTime) interval of -1,+1 hour around their planned time.

I thought I should create a view and insert into the view...But apparently you are not allowed to have Subqueries in an updateable view table?
how would i go about adding this constraint?

Note: PaTime and PoTime are planned arrival time and planned departure times whereas arrT and depT are actual arrival and actual departure times, and they are allowed to be different.

SO basically:
1. A flight is added to the flight table (no extra constraints needed)
2. If it's an incoming flight, its Planned arrival time is added to the Arrivals table (again no constraints to worry about).
3. In the Arrivals table, it's Actual arrival time (can be different from planned arrival time), status, and gate is added to the table. This is where I need a constraint! To check if that gate number exists in this table and the Departures table -1 to +1 hours from their Planned arrival/departure times. 
So for this table I need a way of joining Incoming (for Patime) Outgoing (for Potime) time and check for constraints

Comment: why do you separate them into incoming/outgoing and departures/arrivals? seems to have the same fiels. You can do single table with I/O flag and A(rrival)/D(eparture) flag...

Comment: Well there is a table Flights, then there are two types of flights (Incoming/Outgoing)..so in the E/R diagram Flight is the parent, and the INCOMING/OUTGOING are related to Flight by the I.S.A flag.


In incoming/outgoing...the Planned arrival/departure time is stored. In the Arrivals/Departures..the actual arrival/departure times are stored

Comment: Seems like a bit too much specialization to me.  If you really want to have some way to query "incoming" vs. "outgoing" you might consider using views to supply this functionality, but IMO there should be only a single table with flight information in it; otherwise you're going to have a continuing problem keeping those multiple tables synced up.  YMMV.

Comment: It's for a school project and the specifications were given by the prof so there's not much I can do about it. I did try to make my life easier by adding source and destination to the flights table for other queries...but this specific constraint is giving me some trouble. Is there a way of solving this problem with the way the tables are right now?

Answer (score 0):

A constraint can only reference one table.  If you are required to use this data model, you cannot create a constraint that does what you want.

You have a few options

1. Instead of creating a constraint, you can create a stored procedure that does the `INSERT` of a new flight and that implements whatever validations you want.  You then restrict the application from issuing a direct `INSERT` on the tables and require it to use the stored procedure instead.
2. You can keep the existing data model and create an `ON COMMIT` materialized view that combines the data from departures and arrivals and then create a constraint on that materialized view.
3. You can modify the data model so that all the information you need for the constraint is in a single table.